# Why is "pineapple" in English but "ananas" in all other languages?

Tags: etymology, lexicon

Why is "pineapple" in English but "ananas" in all other languages?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure we can/should say [why English uses *pineapple*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pineapple) and not *ananas* without knowing why other languages **do** use *ananas*. And that's out-of-scope for a site about the nuts and bolts of English.

Comment: It's *nanas* in Indonesian anyway. (Without the first **a**).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm so sorry that you don't want to think about such interesting things about your language.

Comment: Interesting to note that [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pineapple) quote the first use of pineapple for this fruit in 1660 and that an english use of ananas predate (1613, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ananas#References))

Comment: It's not that it's not interesting. But it is likely to more on-topic on Linguistics.SE.

Comment: In Spanish, it's also called [piña](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pi%C3%B1a). The etymology of "pineapple" and a few other words is nicely illustrated at [Europe etymology maps](http://imgur.com/a/iVK8a).

Comment: Fun fact: In Brazilian portuguese, it's not called an ananas, but rather "abacaxi".

Comment: The image is wrong.  The Latin word for "pineapple" is "_ananas**a**_."  Totally different.

Comment: @AndyPerfect can you give me any examples or stages with "abacaxi", please? For my collection =)

Comment: @CleverMasha Just a sentence that uses the word abacaxi?

Comment: This *is* on Linguistics.SE already: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/690/weird-behavior-of-two-fruits-names-ananas-pineapple-banana-platano

Comment: Exploration Lackey:Sir we found this sweet tasting fruit should we call it ananas as the others did?
English Explorer:No, Pineapple
Exploration Lackey:But sir that makes no sen....
English Explorer:I SAID, PINEAPPLE!!!

Comment: Uranus was already there.  There can be only one permanent high school joke.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple),

> Columbus encountered the pineapple in 1493 on the Leeward island of Guadeloupe. He called it *piña de Indes*, meaning "pine of the Indians", and brought it back with him to Europe, thus making the pineapple the first bromeliad to leave the New World.

(Actually, this probably isn't quite right ... since *piña* also means *pinecone* in Spanish, and since pineapples look nothing like pine trees but quite a bit like pinecones, the meaning was undoubtedly "pinecone of the Indians".)

The question is: why did the English adapt the name *pineapple* from Spanish (which originally meant *pinecone* in English) while most European countries eventually adapted the name *ananas,* which came from the Tupi word *nanas* (also meaning pineapple).

This is pure speculation, but it may have to do with the fact that there were English colonies in the New World, and these had lots of trade with the Caribbean. If the fruit was called by one name in the Caribbean and a different name in Spain, the English could easily have ended up using the Caribbean name, while the rest of Europe used the Spanish name.

Comment: Best guess:  It was an exotic name for an exotic fruit

Comment: By the way, in Spanish they are more commonly called *piñas* rather than *ananás*.

Comment: I'm Spanish and I want to say that never in my life I have heard this fruit called ananás. It's piña.

Answer (score 30):

Never believe everything you read on the internet.  That list is hand-picked in order to try to prove a point.  While it's true that most European languages use some variant of "ananas", it is far from the truth to claim that English is the only one to use "pineapple", or that there is not a lot of variation in the terms that are used.

Here is an incomplete list I compiled from Google Translate:

```
Language           Word for "pineapple"  Pronunuciation (according to Google)
--------           --------------------  --------------
Afrikaans          pynappel
Armenian           արքայախնձոր         ark’ayakhndzor
Catalan            pinya
Chichewa           chinanazi
Chinese            菠萝                  Bōluó
Filipino           pinya
Frisian            pineappel
Galician           piña
Hausa              abarba
Igbo               afiapulu
Japanese           パイナップル           Painappuru
Khmer              ម្នាស់                  mneasa
Korean             (not allowed by SE)   pain-aepeul
Kurdish            sifir
Lao                ຫມາກນັດ              maknad
Malayalam          പൈനാപ്പിൾ          paināppiḷ
Maori              Tuhinga o mua
Mongolian          хан боргоцой          khan borgotsoi
Myanmar (Burmese)  နာနတ်ပင်           nar naat pain
Portuguese (pt-BR) abacaxi
Sesotho            phaphaenapole
Shona              chinanai
Telugu             పైనాపిల్                Paināpil
Thai               สับปะรด                S̄ạbpard
Vietnamese         dứa
Welsh              pîn-afal
Xhosa              iphayinaphu
Yoruba             ope oyinbo
Zulu               iphayinaphu
```

So I could just as easily ask

> Why is it *ananas* in French, but *pineapple* in "all" other languages?
>
> ```
> Language           Word for "pineapple"  Pronunuciation (according to Google)
> --------           --------------------  --------------
> Afrikaans          pynappel
> Catalan            pinya
> English            pineapple
> Filipino           pinya
> French             **ananas**
> Frisian            pineappel
> Galician           piña
> Japanese           パイナップル           Painappuru
> Korean             (not allowed by SE)   pain-aepeul
> Malayalam          പൈനാപ്പിൾ          paināppiḷ
> Sesotho            phaphaenapole
> Telugu             పైనాపిల్                Paināpil
> Welsh              pîn-afal
> Xhosa              iphayinaphu
> Zulu               iphayinaphu
> ```

Comment: I dont know how you trusted google translate but take a look at this. This is far more credible than google translate, I'm not a native english speaker and I know how much it gets it wrong.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/ananas

Comment: FYI, it's "anasa pandu" in Telugu, which means "anasa fruit". And "kaitachchakka" in Malayalam. http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Pineapple.html

Answer (score 18):

When European (English) explorers discovered them they called them pineapples because of their resemblance to pine cones from conifer trees.

> The word "pineapple" in English was first recorded in 1398, when it was originally used to describe the reproductive organs of conifer trees (now termed pine cones). The term "pine cone" for the reproductive organ of conifer trees was first recorded in 1694. When European explorers discovered this tropical fruit in the Americas, they called them "pineapples" (first so referenced in 1664 due to resemblance to what is now known as the pine cone).[7][8]
>   In the scientific binomial Ananas comosus, ananas, the original name of the fruit, comes from the Tupi word nanas, meaning "excellent fruit",[9] as recorded by André Thevet in 1555, and comosus, "tufted", refers to the stem of the fruit. Other members of the Ananas genus are often called "pine", as well, in other languages. In Spanish, pineapples are called piña ("pine cone"), or ananá (ananás) (example, the piña colada drink). (Wikipedia)

Comment: The European explorers who discovered pineapples were undoubtedly Spanish or Portuguese, since they are South American in origin. But since they're also called *piña* in Spanish, this answer is probably close to correct.

Comment: @ Peter Shor: I assume that they called them ananas and not pineapples then. The question was about the origin of the English name and not the Spanish or Potuguese.

Comment: There was a prior use of ananas in english (at least by Samuel Purchas *Pligrimage* in 1613 according [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ananas#References))

Comment: I don't think we are discussing whether "ananas" or "pineapple" was used first, but where it came from and why the English language does not use "ananas" today. I would say that whoever introduced the ananas to the public first used the term "pineapple" and that is how the word became the accepted name for the fruit.

Comment: Incidentally, a similar discussion revolves around maracuja, passion fruit and granadilla in the German language.

Comment: I was just highlighting that wikipedia might be wrong in the sentence *"When European explorers discovered this tropical fruit in the Americas, they called them "pineapples"* since it appears that (**naive and personal hypothesis**): when European explorers discovered this tropical fruit in the Americas, they adopt/adapt the names given by natives: nana, this usage spread in most language (and even been used in english once), but later around 1660, the term pineapple araised (due to resemblance to what is now known as the pine cone) and overwhelmed ananas.

Comment: And this is in fact the core of this question. By the way, I think your sentence "Whoever introduced the ananas to the public first used the term pineapple(...)" is the proper answer to this question.

Comment: Cilantro - Coreander - the Spanish Inquisition

Comment: There are ***two*** names used in Spanish for the pineapple, *piña* (as in *piña colada*) and *ananás*. A reasonable hypothesis is that one got translated into English, and the other into most other European languages.

Comment: You should cite the source of your quote. I see the lack of a citation as the only explanation for having fewer upvotes than a later, similar answer. Otherwise, it is a good and thirst provoking answer.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly several late mentions have *both* terms

"I was thinking on the man to whom we are in a great measure obliged for the production and culture of the exotic, we were speaking of, in this kingdom; Sir Matthew Decker;the first **ananas or pine-apple**, that was brought to perfection in England, grew in his garden at Richmond."
Bernard de Mandeville: The Fable of Bees ([**1733**](http://books.google.com/books?id=QJ9YAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA401&dq=The%20first%20ananas,%20or%20pine-apple,%20that%20was%20brought%20to%20perfection%20in%20England,%20grew%20in%20his%20garden%20at%20Richmond&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=DneCUui-C8ii4gS1vICYAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20first%20ananas,%20or%20pine-apple,%20that%20was%20brought%20to%20perfection%20in%20England,%20grew%20in%20his%20garden%20at%20Richmond&f=false))

and
Th Baldwin: Short Practical Directions For The Culture Of The Ananas; Or Pine Apple Plant (**[1813](http://books.google.com/books?id=-1sWnQEACAAJ&dq=Baldwin%20%20Short%20Practical%20Directions%20for%20the%20Culture%20of%20the%20Ananas&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=MXaCUrXbGueG4gTn34BQ&redir_esc=y)**)

There is also the variant **anana**, eg in Th F Gordon (**[1831](http://books.google.com/books?id=PIRJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22the%20anana%22&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=qnGCUp3ZHaTn4gT1j4CwCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20anana%22&f=false)**) the History of America: "The Anana, or Pine Apple"

It seems both terms, and to a lesser extent 'anana' might have been current at least in the early part of the 19th century.